# MySQL returns results, Laravel Eloquent returns empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

This is driving me nuts. I have a super simple query that runs correctly in MySQL but returns no results in Laravel Eloquent:
Laravel Code that returns no results.

```
$feedback = FeaturedFeedback::where("company_id", "=", $company->id);

if ($request->category != "") {
    $category = Category::where("name", "=", $request->category)->first();
}

if ($category) {
    $feedback->where("category_id", "=", $category->id);
}

$feedback->get();
```

When I look at the query logs, this is the query that runs:

```
select * from `featured_feedback` where `company_id` = 8 and `category_id` = 1
```

When I run that query directly on the DB, it returns 4 results. Driving me nuts. It's one table, SQL strict mode is false, no joins, clean query. Thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're chaining multiple conditions onto the `$feedback` query builder instance but not capturing the final result back into the `$feedback` variable.

```
$feedbackQuery = FeaturedFeedback::where("company_id", "=", $company->id);

if ($request->category != "") {
    $category = Category::where("name", "=", $request->category)->first();
}

if ($category) {
    $feedbackQuery->where("category_id", "=", $category->id);
}

$feedback = $feedbackQuery->get();
```

Comment: ugh...super simple and obvious answer!! lol thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In the "FeaturedFeedback" model  add a relationship

```
public function category(){

   return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

use [when](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#conditional-clauses) conditioning instead of if condition

```
$feedback = FeaturedFeedback::where("company_id",$company->id)->when(!empty($request->category),function ($query)use($request){

            $query->whereHas('category',function ($query)use($request){
                $query->where("name",$request->category);
            });
        })->get();
```